# In a bndrun file, how to pass properties in -runvm which have spaces?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bnd, bndtools

In a `.bndrun` file I have:

```
-runvm: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${workspace}/com.myproject/conf/logging.properties
```

When I run the run descriptor, the console shows:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class and
```

That's because of the following generated command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Documents and Settings\Dan\eclipse-workspaces\workspace/com.myproject/conf/logging.properties
```

The space is obviously upsetting it. Normally quote marks are the solution to this. But if I add them, they seem to be stripped out:

```
-runvm: -Djava.util.logging.config.file="${workspace}/com.myproject/conf/logging.properties"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in bnd, might be because the backslashes of windows. In this case, since you're relative to the workspace, you might want to address the properties relative?

Can you file a bug?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a macro to get rid of the backslashes, till the "bug" is fixed.

```
  # replace backslash with slash
  workspace.unix = ${replace;${workspace};(\\\\);/}
```